# Python JSON parser and filterer getting a KeyError every time

Tags: python, json

I am writing a program that is supposed to filter specific results of the JSON file content in the URL. I wanted to filter out any ***description***, ***keywords***, and ***title*** with the name "***Andromeda***". I have written the program and it does run on some pages, whereas on other pages, I keep getting errors and I do not know why. Here is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

#Page = (number change)
url = "https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q=galaxy&page=10"

response = urlopen(url)
data_json = json.loads(response.read())
#Filtering out the results that relate to the word
planets = [i for i in data_json['collection']['items'] if 'Andromeda' in i['data'][0]['title']]
planets1 = [i for i in data_json['collection']['items'] if 'Andromeda' in i['data'][0]['keywords']]
planets2 = [i for i in data_json['collection']['items'] if 'Andromeda' in i['data'][0]['description']]
print(planets)
print("--------------------------------------------")
print(planets1)
print("--------------------------------------------")
print(planets2)
```

Here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:Filter&Search.py", line 11, in <module>
    planets1 = [i for i in data_json['collection']['items'] if 'Andromeda' in i['data'][0]['keywords']]
  File "C:Filter&Search.py", line 11, in <listcomp>
    planets1 = [i for i in data_json['collection']['items'] if 'Andromeda' in i['data'][0]['keywords']]
KeyError: 'keywords'
```

Here is some of the content of my JSON file that I have tried to read and go through:

```
{
  "collection": {
    "version": "1.0",
    "href": "http://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q=galaxy&page=1",
    "items": [
      {
        "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA04921/collection.json",
        "data": [
          {
            "center": "JPL",
            "title": "Andromeda Galaxy",
            "nasa_id": "PIA04921",
            "media_type": "image",
            "keywords": [
              "Galaxy Evolution Explorer GALEX"
            ],
            "date_created": "2003-12-10T22:41:32Z",
            "description_508": "This image is from NASA Galaxy Evolution Explorer is an observation of the large galaxy in Andromeda, Messier 31. The Andromeda galaxy is the most massive in the local group of galaxies that includes our Milky Way.",
            "secondary_creator": "NASA/JPL/California Institute of Technology",
            "description": "This image is from NASA Galaxy Evolution Explorer is an observation of the large galaxy in Andromeda, Messier 31. The Andromeda galaxy is the most massive in the local group of galaxies that includes our Milky Way."
          }
        ],
        "links": [
          {
            "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA04921/PIA04921~thumb.jpg",
            "rel": "preview",
            "render": "image"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/PIA04634/collection.json",
        "data": [
          {
```

Comment: On some pages, the `data` section does not contain an item named `keywords`.

Comment: Is there any way I can fix the functionality of the program to make it search for keywords if it exists? Because in pages like 11, keywords do exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will skip over those posts that don't have 'keywords' in the data dictionary

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

#Page = (number change)
url = "https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q=galaxy&page=10"

response = urlopen(url)
data_json = json.loads(response.read())
#Filtering out the results that relate to the word
planets = [i for i in data_json['collection']['items'] if 'Andromeda' in i['data'][0]['title']]
planets1 = [i for i in data_json['collection']['items'] if 'keywords' in i['data'][0] and 'Andromeda' in i['data'][0]['keywords']]
planets2 = [i for i in data_json['collection']['items'] if 'Andromeda' in i['data'][0]['description']]
print(planets)
print("--------------------------------------------")
print(planets1)
print("--------------------------------------------")
print(planets2)
```

You can use this to print out if the 'keywords' were not found in the dictionary

```
planets1 = []
for i in data_json['collection']['items']:
    if 'keywords' in i['data'][0] and 'Andromeda' in i['data'][0]['keywords']:
        planets1.append(i)
    else: 
        print('keywords not found')
```

if you want list comprehension you could do this:

```
planets1 = [i if 'keywords' in i['data'][0] and 'Andromeda' in i['data'][0]['keywords'] else print('keywords not found') for i in data_json['collection']['items']] # will generate None items (those items when it just printed out instead of when you wanted to add it with Andromeda)
planets1 = list(filter(lambda x: x, planets1)) # removes None from list
```

Comment: Thank you so much! If I wanted to make the program not skip posts that have keywords, but print a statement if keywords don't exist. How would I implement it?

Comment: I tried running the program on pages like 11 that have keywords. Unfortunately, it has not located any keywords with the word Andromeda

Comment: Thank you so much! kindly, can you tell me what does [0] mean between data and keywords?

Comment: @ProgrammingPower the [0] is looking at the first index inside of the data element in the dictionary (I). This is because the data element contains a list of elements (not a dictionary), so you are indexing into that first element to look at the various other elements that you want such as keywords, title, and description.